# How to write code that can use the same type defined in multiple assemblies

Tags: c#, .net

This is **not** an issue of having a reference to multiple assemblies that have the same type defined (I know to use `alias` in that scenario).

My issue is that I'm writing a helper library for the `System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext` type. I would like to let my library be used with any version of that class. The problem I've run into is that it was originally defined in the System.Data.Services.Client.dll assembly with the .NET 3.5 Framework. Since then, Microsoft has released out of band updates in an assembly named Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll.

When my library is used by another project, it works fine with the multiple versions of the Microsoft dll, but it won't work with the assembly released with the framework. If I change my library to use the System assembly, then it won't work with the Microsoft assemblies.

I thought about assembly redirects, but that doesn't work if the assembly name is different.

Is anyone aware of a solution to this, or am I going to have to make a decision on which assembly my library will work with (or provide multiple versions of my library)?

Comment: I don't see why this is not simple a conditional compilation scenario?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean using preprocessor directives? If that's what you are referring to, then that's what I meant by "or provide multiple versions of my library" comment. But I would prefer to have a single dll that everyone can use.

Comment: Create a wrapper class and use the target via reflection?

Comment: The main entry point to this library is passing in an instance of the `DataServiceContext` to a method (to be more specific, it's an extension method for that type). One option would be to make it an extension method off of `object`, and use reflection from there, but I avoid writing extension methods for the `object` type because I think that's a bad idea (and the extension method will appear for all types when it should only apply to a specific type).